# Segmentation Fault reason assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to understand the reasoning behind segmentation fault in my program.
I'm purposely commenting out the exit system call so that the program does not terminate. It is the last line of code in my program.
Why is the exact reason for the segmentation fault here?

(I think that the code is irrelevant here)

EDIT:
line of the code responsible for the exit code:

`int $0x80    #make the system call`

Comment: You think what?!!11 Come on.

Comment: @unwind the point is that the program works and I KNOW that it wont work without exit call. I just want to know what happens when there isn't a call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memory always contains some value (even if just zeroes), and the processor will try to execute those bytes as instructions. The bytes might not make sense (illegal instruction) or the instructions themselves may cause a fault. If you happen to have valid instructions not causing a fault, you will eventually hit a page which is not mapped and you will get a fault then. If you are extremely lucky, the garbage code might have an endless loop (or an exit syscall ;)) in which case you won't get a fault.

Answer (score 3):

The reason it faults is likely that execution continues into memory which is either not valid to execute from, or which doesn't contain actual code but rather random garbage. It's pretty easy to imagine that random garbage when executed as code can produce an operation which in turn gives a segfault.